# how to configure dynamic inbound for Spring integration mail?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration

I am new in spring mail integration, and bellow i put my configuration for **`mail:inbound-channel-adapter`**. But i want that the attribute **store-uri** to be dynamique, and i can update it from my Java controller. Because this attribute is not constante in my context of application.

```
<int-mail:inbound-channel-adapter id="pop3ShouldDeleteTrue"
                    store-uri="imaps://tata:tata@imap.gmail.com:993/inbox"
                    channel="receiveChannel"
                    should-delete-messages="true"
                    auto-startup="false"
                    java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties">
        <!-- Will poll every 20 seconds -->
        <int:poller fixed-rate="20000"/>
</int-mail:inbound-channel-adapter>
```

Comment: You show here a technical challenge. Can you describe a business requirement, how it really should look from end-user perspective, what is the reason to change the mail box to poll at runtime? Having that we may help you find some other solution.

Answer (score 2):

The URL is a `final` field in the inbound adapter (actually an `ImapMailReceiver` component passed into a `MailReceivingMessageSource`) so it can't be updated.

The only way to change the URL would be to rebuild both classes and inject them into the `SourcePollingChannelAdapter` that represents the inbound adapter.

However, that won't be thread-safe so I don't think it's safe to do that in a web container.

It's probably easier to simply construct an `ImapMailReceiver` on-demand and call the `receive()` method, then use a `MessagingTemplate` to send the message to a channel.

Comment: thank you for your response I'll search how I have to implement your methode.